# javascript pagination creation with first last and 10 number display

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I created pagination and all page numbers are displaying. Sometimes it's breaking the layout. I want to break it down. 10 page number will display like below. Please suggest me on my code how can I achieve it.

```
<<first <previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 next> last>>
```

To display all page number, I applied below code

```js
var items = [];
var paginationRow = 10;
var maxPage = 77;
for (var page = 1; page <= maxPage; page++) {
  var html = "";
  if (page % paginationRow == 1) {
    html += '<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">';
  }
  html += '<li class="page-item">';
  html += '<a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="loadPageParam(' + page + ')">' + page + '</a>';
  html += '</li>';
  if (page % paginationRow == 0) {
    html += '</ul>';
  }
  items.push(html);
};
$('<div/>', {
  'class': '',
  html: items.join('')
}).appendTo('#pagination');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```